# Non-public schema for schema migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rails-activerecord

My application is using Postgresql's schemas rather than multiple databases, so each environment will have its own schema. That is, I'm using one database with a `production`, `development`, and `test` schema. I've dropped the `public` schema from this database.

I've created my first migration, but when I run `rake db:migrate` I get an error stating

```
PG::InvalidSchemaName: ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying(255) NOT NULL)
```

I've included the `schema_search_path` in my `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  username: 
  password: 
  database: 
  host: localhost
  port: 5433
  schema_search_path: 'development'
```

Since my application isn't going to be using any features that would make it multitenant, I don't really want to use a large gem such as Apartment. Is there any way to make the `rake db:migrate` command work with my schemas?

Comment: In a word, you need to set the search_path accordingly. No idea how it's done in Rails, but a simple query after connecting should do the trick.

Comment: Haha, yes of course, but I'm asking if it's possible to do with the plain `rake db:migrate` task. I don't know how to set the `search_path` in Rails for migrations other than in the `database.yml`.

Comment: You can set the search path by running e.g. `set search_path to production, public`. On DB query before running the follow-up queries. And, it's arguably a bug in rails if setting the search path in the config file works but not when you run migrations.

Comment: Yeah I think it is. I created a custom task that created the schema by placing the environment in front of the table name (i.e. `"development"."schema_migrations"`) and it worked. I followed this up by running the migration command and that also worked, so for some reason the `schema_migration` table creation method isn't following `schema_search_path` from `database.yml`.

Comment: @josh thank you can you elaborate on your solution. i'm getting the very same error

Answer (score -1):

Because you don't have a schema called development in your database.

Comment: No that's not the issue, I already created the schemas in the database. I think it's an issue with Rails, or at least was an issue at the time, where it would not add the prefix to the table when creating the initial tables. It would work afterwards when I added `set search_path to production,public`.